# How to compare to dataset's ids to find the oldest to delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a question about a sql query or best astored procedure that can be run inside a SSIS package that will compare a two data set to see what differs.

My data set includes data which is historic (versionid=0) and prognosis/budget where versionid > 0. Every time a new prognosis or budget is created a new versionid is added (a new row in version table max(versionid) +1 or autoincrement). new budget data is created 1 or 2 times a year, but prognosis is created a least every month.

I want a query or best a stored procedure that can extract the X latest prognosis and Y latest budgets from the version table. There is two bit columns one saying IsPrognosis (1/0) and the second IsBudget (1/0)

When I extract new data, I must compare an existing dataset DimVersion against new extracted data

Let us say DimVersion includes these integer ids (H=hist, B=Bud, P=Prog) Where X=6 (keep 6 latest prognosis and 2 latest budgets)

VersionId = {0 (H), 137(B),152(B), 153(P), 154(P), 155(P),156(P), 157(P), 158(P)} => 158 current prog and 152 current bud

Here is DimVersion table, the source is identical in this test

```
| VersionId     | Name                  | HistoryTo     | IsBudget  | IsHistory     | IsPrognosis   |
|-----------    |---------------------- |-----------    |---------- |-----------    |-------------  |
| 0             | History data          | 200701        | 0         | 1             | 0             |
| 137           | October 2017 Budget   | 201805        | 1         | 0             | 0             |
| 152           | October 2018 Budget   | 201710        | 1         | 0             | 0             |
| 153           | Prognosis nov 2017    | 201805        | 0         | 0             | 1             |
| 154           | Prognosis dec 2017    | 201712        | 0         | 0             | 1             |
| 155           | Prognosis Jan 2018    | 201801        | 0         | 0             | 1             |
| 156           | Prognosis feb 2018    | 201802        | 0         | 0             | 1             |
| 157           | Prognosis mar 2018    | 201803        | 0         | 0             | 1             |
| 158           | Prognosis april 2018  | 201804        | 0         | 0             | 1             |
```

NB! The historyTo column is used later and have nothing to do finding versionids.

Case : Most often it is just one new versionid row being added, but it could happen that more than one new ids rows are added, let us say 159(B) and 160(P)

What is going to happen is if more than 2 budgets, delete the oldest bud in DimVersion (137) and add the new 159. For prognosis we should have exact 6, so if more than 6 delete the oldest here 153 and add the newest 160.

The final result will be

```
  | VersionId   | Name                  | HistoryTo     | IsBudget  | IsHistory     | IsPrognosis   |
|-----------    |---------------------- |-----------    |---------- |-----------    |-------------  |
| 0             | History data          | 200701        | 0         | 1             | 0             |
| 152           | October 2018 Budget   | 201710        | 1         | 0             | 0             |
| 154           | Prognosis dec 2017    | 201712        | 0         | 0             | 1             |
| 155           | Prognosis Jan 2018    | 201801        | 0         | 0             | 1             |
| 156           | Prognosis feb 2018    | 201802        | 0         | 0             | 1             |
| 157           | Prognosis mar 2018    | 201803        | 0         | 0             | 1             |
| 158           | Prognosis april 2018  | 201804        | 0         | 0             | 1             |
| 159           | May 2019 Budget       | 201805        | 1         | 0             | 0             |
| 160           | Prognosis may 2018    | 201805        | 0         | 0             | 1             |
```

137(B) and (150(P) are deleted and 159 and 160 are added

My question is: 
the first extraction query against the  version source gives me the latest 6 prog versionids and 2 bud versionids (and hist=0, but we can ignore it since it will always be in the dataset). This is added to a staging table, Table1. Then this must be compared against the versions from DimVersion which keeps the current versions. The Comparison must at best find the versionids that will be deleted, and the new versions that will be added to dimversion. Versionids are incremental so it always be a higher version id number than max in dim version

So the perfect resultset from the query would be

```
| VersionId     | Action    |
|-----------    |--------   |
| 137           | Delete    |
| 153           | Delete    |
| 159           | Add       |
| 160           | Add       |
```

Of course there are many approaches for a good algorithm here. One of course is to put all rows (deleted, unchanged, added) in the result set. If the comparison does not find any different just end an empty result set or unchanged for all rows in Action column

If any of you have a good solution, please answer this post

Thanks Geir

Comment: Sample data in a *tabular* format would really help convey what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry i will of course do that. One moment